# 異なるバージョンのSQL Server 間でリンクサーバを利用できますか？

Tags: sql-server

タイトルの件、SQL Server 2008とSQL Server 2016間でリンクサーバを作成して、双方向に参照と更新は、可能でしょうか？

このあたりのノウハウがある方ご教示ください。
ドキュメント等の場所でも構いません。（当方みつけられませんでした。）

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[リンクサーバー](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/linked-servers-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017)とは

> データベース エンジン の別のインスタンスまたは別のデータベース製品 (Oracle など) のテーブルを含んだ Transact-SQL ステートメントを SQL Serverから実行できるようにすることです。 Microsoft の Access や Excel など、さまざまな種類の OLE DB データ ソースをリンク サーバーとして構成できます。

という機能ですから、対SQL Serverのみバージョン指定があるとは考えられません。OLE DBが使用できれば任意のバージョンへ接続可能と考えるべきでしょう。